# How to arrange image after drag and drop

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I have a slight problem with my code. I'm developing drag and drop where users can drag the sweets out from the jar to the specific target. The process works just fine. However, when I want to drag the sweets from the specific target back to the jar, the sweets overlaps over each other.

This picture below shows that the sweets are placed and arranged neatly. Before I drag the sweets out

[image: Before drag and drop]

[image: After drag and drop]

Then, after the sweets are being drag and drop, it looks like this the second picture.

Based on the picture above, I have drag four sweets into the jar. But the sweets are overlapped and that is why you can see only one sweet in the jar. There is suppose to be four sweets in the jar.

So, can you please help me. How can I arrange back my sweets so that after I dropped them back in the jar, it will be arrange just like the sweets in the first picture.

This is the code.

```
           case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            // // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

            Log.i("drop", "Id First :" + view.getId());
            Log.i("drop", "Id Second :" + v.getId());
            Log.i("value", "Value :" + view.getContentDescription());

            owner.removeView(view);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(88, 88);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, view.getId());


            if(v.getId()==R.id.jaroval)
            {
                RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
                container.addView(view,lp);
                value=container.getChildCount();
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {

                GridLayout container2 = (GridLayout) v;
                container2.setColumnCount(5);
                container2.addView(view);
                cValue=container2.getChildCount();
                value=10-cValue;
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            sound();
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line causes the issue:

```
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, view.getId());
```

You basically say that, the view you're currently adding should be to the right of itself. Instead you need to provide the id of the previous item you added to the jar. To do that you can simply store the id of the item recently added.

Sample code to achieve this:

```
//Create a variable that can be accessed and initialize it as -1
int mostRecentlyAddedView = -1;

//Then in the method you handle drag event
if(mostRecentlyAdddedView == -1){ //This is the very first view, therefore no need to add toRight layout.
   // update the variable
   mostRecentlyAdddedView = view.getId();

  // ... do other things here
} else {
  // ... other things
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(88, 88);
  lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mostRecentlyAdddedView);
  // ... other things
}
```

Comment: Can you show me some example on how can I store the id of the item recently added? Thank you

Comment: Thank you sir. I've tried the code. However it's not working. May I ask where should I put `if (v.getId()==R.id.jaroval)` code? Inside the else statement or what?

Comment: this if/else if only to figure out what layout parameters to set to the view you'd like to add. You should keep rest of your code.